# Temperature converter in python

Tags: python

I went through a couple of converters in python but they entered the int value seperately. If the input is 100C i want the output in F and if its 50F i want it in C. I'm new to python and tried some simple lines but the error says its impossible to concatenate str and int.

```
a = raw_input(" enter here")
char = "f"
char2 = "c"
for s in a:
    if s in char:
        b=(5*(a-32))/9
        print(b,"c")
        continue
    elif s in char2:
        d = (9*a/5)+32
        print(d,"f")
        continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the user will enter a number followed by the unit, you need to only check if the last character of the string to understand which conversion to do.

You can use slicing, here is an example:

```
>>> a = '45F'
>>> a[-1]
'F'
>>> a[:-1]
'45'
```

Of course `'45'` is a string not a number, converting it to a number with `int()` will allow you do math on it.

Putting all that together, we have something like this:

```
a = raw_input('Enter here: ')
number = int(a[:-1])
letter = a[-1].lower()
if letter == 'f':
    print('{} in C is {}'.format(a, 5*(number-32)/9))
if letter == 'c':
    print('{} in F is {}'.format(a, 9*(number/5)*32))
```

Comment: wow :D i never thought of slicing unless it was a list :) great! this is simple and neat!!! thanks :)

Comment: `.format` is the new [format syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)